# write.csv() using format() adds white spaces to NA

Tags: r

Incidentally, I have found this problem with `write.csv()` and NA values if using `format()`:

```
d <- data.frame(id=1:10, f=0.1*(1:10),f2=0.01*(1:10))
d$f2[3] <- NA
summary(d)
       id              f               f2         
 Min.   : 1.00   Min.   :0.100   Min.   :0.01000  
 1st Qu.: 3.25   1st Qu.:0.325   1st Qu.:0.04000  
 Median : 5.50   Median :0.550   Median :0.06000  
 Mean   : 5.50   Mean   :0.550   Mean   :0.05778  
 3rd Qu.: 7.75   3rd Qu.:0.775   3rd Qu.:0.08000  
 Max.   :10.00   Max.   :1.000   Max.   :0.10000  
                                 NA's   :1        
format(d, nsmall=3)
   id     f    f2
1   1 0.100 0.010
2   2 0.200 0.020
3   3 0.300    NA
4   4 0.400 0.040
5   5 0.500 0.050
6   6 0.600 0.060
7   7 0.700 0.070
8   8 0.800 0.080
9   9 0.900 0.090
10 10 1.000 0.100 
format(d$f2, nsmall = 3)
 [1] "0.010" "0.020" "   NA" "0.040" "0.050" "0.060" "0.070" "0.080" "0.090" "0.100"
format(d$f2[3])
[1] "NA"
write.csv(format(d,nsmall=3),file="test.csv",row.names = FALSE)
d2 <- read.csv("test.csv")
summary(d2)
       id              f              f2           
 Min.   : 1.00   Min.   :0.100   Length:10         
 1st Qu.: 3.25   1st Qu.:0.325   Class :character  
 Median : 5.50   Median :0.550   Mode  :character  
 Mean   : 5.50   Mean   :0.550                     
 3rd Qu.: 7.75   3rd Qu.:0.775                     
 Max.   :10.00   Max.   :1.000
```

I check test.csv and find that the cell corresponding to d$f[3] is not `"NA"` but `"   NA"`

```
d2 <- read.csv("test.csv", na.strings="   NA")
summary(d2)
       id              f               f2         
 Min.   : 1.00   Min.   :0.100   Min.   :0.01000  
 1st Qu.: 3.25   1st Qu.:0.325   1st Qu.:0.04000  
 Median : 5.50   Median :0.550   Median :0.06000  
 Mean   : 5.50   Mean   :0.550   Mean   :0.05778  
 3rd Qu.: 7.75   3rd Qu.:0.775   3rd Qu.:0.08000  
 Max.   :10.00   Max.   :1.000   Max.   :0.10000  
                                 NA's   :1
```

Should this behavior of `format()`, adding white spaces to NAs, not be considered a bug?
Not a critical issue as using format() within write.csv() is not really necessary (I found this problem in a very particular case), but, in principle, NAs should not be affected by any format. One thing is having a nicer print to the console and another actually saving those white spaces to a file that could be read back into R.

Comment: It is not write.csv, issue, it is from `format` i.e. check `format(d$f2, nsmall = 3)`

Comment: You may use `sprintf` i.e. `d[] <- lapply(d, sprintf, fmt = '%0.3f')`

Comment: Right, I reformulate my question. There are several alternatives, but the issue is that format(x, nsmall=3) should not affect NAs, NAs do not have decimal places.

Comment: The added spaces are so NA will right-align when printing to the console. As the manual page says: "Format an R object for pretty printing." For example, `cat(format(d$f2), sep="\n")`.

Comment: But that is precisely what I think is not correct: NA should not be right-aligned if saved to a file. If you format 3.1416, write to csv and read it back, you still get 3.1416. But if you do the same with an NA, you do not get back an NA but a char. Note that the number of white spaces could change from column to column, so the problem cannot be solved with na.strings. Pretty printing to the console is not the same as writing to a file, you do not read back from the console. Anyway, I think my point is clear, just wish to know where I could raise it fro R devs to consider it,